# PDF viewer with selectable text

Tags: pdf

Is there a good PDF viewer in the Ubuntu sources that lets me select and copy text? Okular for KDE is a great app, as it has a far greater number of tools than Document Viewer does. I see the repos have Okular, but I would like to avoid installing all the KDE dependencies that come with it. However, all I really need to do is select and copy text from a pdf. What will allow me to do this?

Comment: Evince (aka Document Viewer) does. What's wrong with using it?

Comment: Whether  text is selectable or not depends on the pdf file, not the viewer. If the text is not *as an image*, all viewers offer selectable text.

Comment: And so it is, @Jacob. Evince is fine in that regard, muru. It just so happens the first document I tried to select text from in Ubuntu was one of the un-selectable type.

Comment: @DavidH does it have text or images of text?

Comment: @muru I just assumed because it was an official US gov. document that it was a text-based pdf. Seeing as how I couldn't select text, apparently it was an unconverted scan. I checked Document Viewer against a PDF I created in LibreOffice, and lo and behold it had all the text tools I was looking for.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/ - Free pdf editing using PdfEdit. Complete editing of pdf documents is made possible with PDFedit. You can change either raw pdf objects (for advanced  users) or use redefined gui functions. Functions can be easily added as everything is based on a script. - from repository meta

Comment: Hi David, posted an answer nevertheless that offers a solution in case of "image"- pdf's.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby thanks for the tip. I thought the only way to appreciate was to upvote, a privilege which I am as yet denied.

Comment: Okular out-of-the-box does not select text, but it can select text if you enable "text selection tool" from the Tools menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, if text in a pdf document is *selectable* as text or not, depends on whether the text is in the document *as an image* or *as text*. In the latter case, all `pdf` viewers do support selecting text as far as I know.

#### No options with text in a pdf image?

You do have a few options however to make the text in a document "readable"

One relatively unknown, but imo very nice option to (also) convert `pdf` images to text is `gimageReader`:

[image]

It has a nice interface and reads the selected text, displayed next to your pdf document.

to install, use its ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sandromani/gimagereader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimagereader
```

#### Note

You might need/want to additionally install `tesseract` ocr tools for specific languages to use:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

and specific languages, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng
```

Specific languages can also easily be selected by using `synaptic`.

---

#### Edit

(at least) From 18.04, gImageReader is in the repositories, so no need to add the ppa manually anymore.

Comment: Now that's very useful toward my original question! Thanks!

Comment: @DavidH glad it helps :)

Comment: you actually don't need the ppa, at least for 18.04. There you can just do:
sudo apt install gimagereader

Comment: @VincentGerris True! edited it into the answer. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look for [master PDF editor](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/). It's a great application for all tasks you could do with a PDF file.

Some Features:

- Edit PDF text, images and pages with full editing features
- Create new PDF or edit existing ones.
- Add and/or edit bookmarks in PDF files.
- Encrypt and/or protect PDF files using 128 bit encryption.
- Convert XPS files into PDF.
- Add PDF controls (like buttons, checkboxes, lists, etc.) into your
  PDFs.

and many more features.<sub>[source](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/)</sub>

You can download it from [here](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/).

Or you can install it directly:

```
 sudo apt-get install master-pdf-editor
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. However, it won't do me much good in this specific case. As  Jacob Vlijm pointed out, some PDF's won't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDF Studio. It is the best PDF editing software out there (for Linux). Download and try @ http://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/